# How to properly annotate a ContextManager in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing, contextmanager

How can I annotate the yield type of a `contextmanager` in PyCharm so that it properly guesses the type of the value used in the `with` clauses - just as it guesses that the `f` created in `with open(...) as f` is a file?

For example, I have a context manager like this:

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def temp_borders_file(geometry: GEOSGeometry, name='borders.json'):
    with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        borders_file = Path(dir) / name
        with borders_file.open('w+') as f:
            f.write(geometry.json)
        yield borders_file

with temp_borders_file(my_geom) as borders_f:
    do_some_code_with(borders_f...)
```

How do I let PyCharm know that every `borders_f` created like this is a `pathlib.Path` (and thus enable the autocompletion for the `Path` methods on `border_f`)? Of course, I can make a comment like `# type: Path` after every `with` statement, but it seems that this can be done by properly annotating `temp_border_file`.

I tried `Path`, `typing.Iterator[Path]` and `typing.Generator[Path, None, None]` as the return type of `temp_border_file`, as well as adding `# type: Path` on `borders_file` within the context manager's code, but it seems like it doesn't help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dirty workaround below. Will break `mypy`. Better don't use it.

---

I believe you can use `ContextManager` from `typing`, e.g.:

```
import contextlib
from typing import ContextManager
from pathlib import Path


@contextlib.contextmanager
def temp_borders_file() -> ContextManager[Path]:
    pass


with temp_borders_file() as borders_f:
    borders_f  # has type Path here
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try this shortly - need Python 3.6 for that.

Comment: `typing.ContextManager` is deprecated since version 3.9.  Should I still use it or use `contextlib.AbstractContextManager` in the same place?

Comment: @audeoudh I think so, yes.

Comment: This doesn't make logical sense because decorators wrap the function to do something else - so putting ` -> ContextManager[Path]` suggests that after being wrapped with `@contextmanager` you'd end up with something like `ContextManager[ContextManager[Path]]` !

Comment: Well, true. It should be fixed on the PyCharm side in [PY-36444](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36444).

Comment: This did not work for me. Instead I have `from typing import Generator; def my_func() -> Generator[Path, None, None]: ...`. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 9):

This is a current PyCharm issue: [PY-36444](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36444)

A workaround for the issue is to rewrite an example code of:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def generator_function():
    yield "some value"

with generator_function() as value:
    print(value.upper())  # no PyCharm autocompletion
```

to

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import ContextManager

def wrapper() -> ContextManager[str]:
    @contextmanager
    def generator_function():
        yield "some value"

    return generator_function()

with wrapper() as value:
    print(value.upper())  # PyCharm autocompletion works
```

There is also an easier workaround of annotating the return type with `ContextManager[str]` but there are multiple reasons against this:

- mypy will correctly emit errors for this annotation, as described in more detail in the PyCharm issue.
- this is not guaranteed to work in the future because PyCharm will hopefully fix the issue and therefore break this workaround