# Type hinting on a context manager processing paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Code (fixed with the help of @juanpa.arrivillaga:

```py
"""Helpers that can be used for context management."""

import logging
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, Iterator, Optional

_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@contextmanager
def working_directory(temporary_path: Union[Path, str], initial_path: Optional[Union[Path, str]] = None) -> Iterator[None]:
    """Changes working directory, and returns to `initial_path` on exit. It's needed for PRAW for example,
    because it looks for praw.ini in Path.cwd(), but that file could be kept in a different directory.

    `initial_path` can be used for example to change working directory relative to the script path, or
    to end up in a different directory than Path.cwd() of the calling script.

    Inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742317/how-can-i-change-directory-with-python-pathlib
    """
    _LOGGER.debug('Working directory of the calling script: %s', Path.cwd())
    _LOGGER.debug('temporary_path = %s', temporary_path)
    _LOGGER.debug('initial_path = %s', initial_path)

    if not isinstance(temporary_path, (Path, str)):
        raise TypeError('"temporary_path" is not of type `Path` or `str`')

    if initial_path is None:
        initial_path = Path.cwd()
    else:
        initial_path = Path(initial_path).absolute()
        if not initial_path.is_dir():
            initial_path = initial_path.parent

    try:
        os.chdir(initial_path / temporary_path)
        _LOGGER.debug('Temporarily changed working directory to: %s', Path.cwd())
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(initial_path)
```

Are the typing annotations that I've done correct?

Also, is there a more pythonic way to write this function? What would you change? I'll post it in CodeReview too.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ... but these lines force `initial_path` to be `Path`: `if initial_path is not Path.cwd():`, `initial_path = Path(initial_path).absolute()`

Comment: no, it absolutely doesn't. What if `if initial_path is not Path.cwd()` is *false* (which by the way, it *will always be false*). Just convert both the `Path` objects at the top of the function. Your `if` doesn't even have an `else`.

Comment: you're right @juanpa.arrivillaga, you're a genius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typing is fine, you simply have bugs revealed by mypy in your code. If both `initial_path` and `temporary_path` are `str` then this will fail. That's why it's complaining.

You only convert to `Path` in one branch you don't have an `else` (bad practice, IMO), so when you reach the line:

`initial_path / temporary_path` it *could be* that both of those are `str`.

Note, `mypy` doesn't know this, but  `if initial_path is not Path.cwd()` is not correct. This statement will always be False. Don't compare things with `is` unless you mean object identity, and in this case, you don't.

Consider:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path().cwd() is  Path().cwd()
False
```

Just do:

```
def working_directory(
    temporary_path: Union[Path, str],
    initial_path: Union[Path, str] = Path.cwd()
) -> Iterator[None]:
    temporary_path = Path(temporary_path)
    initial_path = Path(initial_path)
```

At the beginning of your function.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335263/how-to-properly-annotate-a-contextmanager-in-pycharm), the proper type hinting for a context manager in this case is `def working_directory(...) -> ContextManager[Iterator[None]]` where `ContextManager` is imported from the `typing` module